# Area of circle inscribed in two quarter circles

Tags: geometry, circles

So our math teacher gave us this puzzle:

[image: A diagram of a circle inscribed two quarter circles]

We need to find the area of the circle.
The equation for the two quarter circles are:
$x^2+y^2=1$,
$(x-1)^2+y^2=1$.

I found that the equation for the circle is $(x-0.5)^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$.
I want to find out $a$, as the circle is tangent to both the two quarter circles.
Thanks!

Comment: Find where $x^2+y^2=1$ and the circle intersect. They are tangent when two points of intersection in the first quadrant coincide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's your diagram with a few lines, points and line lengths added:

[image: OP's picture with a few lines, points and line lengths added]

In particular, $A$ is the origin, $O$ is the center of the green circle, $B$ is the point where the green and red circles are tangent to each other, $C$ is the tangent point between the green circle and the $x$-axis (so it's also where the line normal to the $x$-axis starts from to go through $O$), and $DF$ (which goes through $B$) is the common tangent line at $B$ to the green and red circles. Thus, since $OB$ and $AB$ are both perpendicular to $DF$ at $B$, these lines coincide, i.e., $AB$ is the common normal line to $DF$. Thus, it goes through the centers of both circles, i.e., both $A$ and $O$.

Since $\lvert AB\rvert = 1$, with $\lvert OB\rvert = a$, then $\lvert OA\rvert = \lvert AB\rvert - \lvert OB\rvert = 1 - a$. Also, $\lvert OC\rvert = a$, and $\lvert AC\rvert = 0.5$ due to symmetry (as you've already determined in your circle equation). Since $\triangle ACO$ is right-angled, using the Pythagorean theorem gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\lvert AC\rvert^2 + \lvert OC\rvert^2 & = \lvert OA\rvert^2 \\
0.5^2 + a^2 & = (1-a)^2 \\
0.25 + a^2 & = 1 - 2a + a^2 \\
2a & = 0.75 \\
a & = 0.375
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$

Comment: The image gives the answer away. $+1$ for your answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I’m still not getting why AO and AB are on the same line. Can you explain it further please?

Comment: @404notfound You're welcome. I've updated my diagram with an extra common circles' tangent line of $DF$, going through $B$, as well as updated my explanation somewhat. Note it's similar to that $OC$ is perpendicular to the green circle tangent line at $C$, i.e., the $x$-axis, but with this just being rotated in the case for $B$. Since this same condition applies to both the green and red circles, as I indicated, then those lines coincide, i.e., $AB$ goes through $O$. Please let me know if there's anything that is still not clear about this.

Comment: @404notfound In case it's still unclear, note Wikipedia's [Circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle) article has it's [Tangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle#Tangent) section stating that "A line drawn perpendicular to a radius through the end point of the radius lying on the circle is a tangent to the circle" and "A line drawn perpendicular to a tangent through the point of contact with a circle passes through the centre of the circle". Putting these together shows there's a common tangent line at $B$ and its perpendicular goes through both circle centers. There's also the ...

Comment: @404notfound (cont.) [answer](/a/1377747) that has a diagram using this principle, this [answer](/a/3356483) stating "Let $P$ be point of tangency. Now, $O_1$ , $P$ and $O_2$ are collinear (as $O_1 P$ and $O_2P$ are perpendicular to same line, the tangent at $P$)". Finally, this [answer's](/a/2855674) diagram shows the common tangent line $EB$, with $B$ being where the circles with centers $Q$ and $P$ meet, and it also shows that $BP$ goes through $Q$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan That makes sense, thanks again